# How to highlight selected row with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery 1.6.4 and I have an html table.  I assign the table an id = "tbl" and then use a click event to dynamically find which row was clicked.  In that row I want to highlight it so the user can see which row was clicked.

I used some code in a jQuery book and modified it for using it with (this).  However, it's not highlighting the row.

Here is my code:

```
$('#tbl tr').click(function() { 
                //$('div.poem-stanza').addClass('highlight');
                $(this).addClass("highlight");
...
```

In firebug I verify that (this) is referencing a tr element, but for some reason the code doesn't work with the highlighting.  What do I need to do for this to work dynamically using (this)?

Based on the comments, I double checked and didn't have .highlight in my css file.  I had added it for other named elements and I had a typo in my reference to the css file.  Thanks to firebug I was able to see everything that loaded and what was missing.

Comment: How is your question title related to to the question itself?

Comment: Post your CSS. That might be the problem.

Comment: Have you created a CSS class called `.highlight`?

Comment: If you are changing just background for highlighted row make sure that you are adding !important in css class so you make sure that your new background is not overwritten with the old property like this [ background-color: #fffff !important; ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this way:

```
$("tr").one("click", "#tbl", function() {
      $(this).addClass("highlight");
});
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/JsRTH/)**

Comment: I used your other code in the jsfiddle, but it's working now!

Answer (score 2):

tr element cannot have background color. In order to highlight a line you have to highlight each td in this row. Assuming you give the tr element the highlight class, add this to your css file:

```
.highlight td { background-color:green; }
```

You will find out that the row colored in green.

Alternately you can do:

```
$('#tbl tr').click(function() { 
      $(this).find('td').addClass("highlight");
});
```

Good Luck!

Comment: I'm sorry, but you're wrong. please see my fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/qrDgC/ . You can definitely color table row elements.

Answer (score 1):

If these rows are dynamically added after the DOM, you're going to need to delegate the click function across the table.

```
$(document).live('click', '#tbl tr', function(){ 
  $(this).addClass('highlight"); 
});
```

Comment: James already explained that event is fired, cause he checked using FireBug console, so probably this is not problem.

Comment: That is correct.  The click event works.  I was missing the css for highlight, I had it with different name.